# Apple's "sparse bundle" format documentation

Tags: filevault, sparsebundle

I have on my hands a corrupted disk drive with a legacy FileVault image (`.sparsebundle` directory) and want to attempt to recover it.

However, publicly available information I could find on this format is... rather sparse. Is there any more or less comprehensive spec available officially or reverse-engineered?

Comment: Sparse documentation for the sparse bundle format? I see what you did there. Personally, I'd make a second disk image, using the same image type as the one FileVault used to use, and then inspect the files within in a hex editor (like the one that comes with emacs) and look for any differences that might be due to corruption. Don't change things you're not sure about though! From what I can tell, you needn't worry about the band files. They seem to be pure data, and if there's any corruption there, you'd have to mount the disk first to find out... Should make the task easier. :)

Comment: There is not public documentation, but you can look at the source HFS http://opensource.apple.com//source/hfs/hfs-305.10.1/CopyHFSMeta/SparseBundle.c